# Saving data using Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have an app which saves the form data to the device using Core Data.

- I can save the data using NSManagedContext
- I can also fetch the data

But, When I go to the .sqlite file on my Mac using the Finder, I don't see the latest data in SQLite file. I can see data I have saved a day back but not the data I saved a few minutes back.

Can anyone help me understand how Core Data is saving my data?

Comment: SQLite uses journal files in addition to the main SQLite file. Maybe you’re not getting all the files?

Comment: There are a total of 3 sqlite files out of which 2 are encrypted

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that, file you are accessing is not actual one. print this line at appdelegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

`print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory,.userDomainMask, true).last! as String)`

in console you will have a full path of .sqlite file location.
Use finder `Command + Shift + G`, and paste that location. Now that file is actual one.

Comment: It is the same path as I was checking earlier, Sharad! I have deleted these files, the data is gone in App. I launched app again saved new data, the files are created but there are 0 rows in the file

Comment: Which data browser you are using?

Comment: I am using sqliteviewer plugin on Google Chrome

Comment: Provide your code, I’ll look into that. Github url will be more convenient.